# Any NSWindowRestoration examples?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-lion, nswindow

I'm having some trouble implementing `NSWindowRestoration` (in 10.7 Lion).  I'm not getting the protocol notifications.

Is there an example app with this implemented somewhere?  I cannot find one on the Apple Developer site.  Thanks!

---

Edit: The question marked as answer is helpful, but the problem in my case was that I was using a menubar-only application.  I guess window restoration doesn't work with dockless apps yet. Snap!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class method `+ (void)restoreWindowWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier state:(NSCoder *)state completionHandler:(void (^)(NSWindow *, NSError *))completionHandler` as described by "El Developer" is only half of the solution.

The class that implements the method (and conforms to the NSWindowRegistration protocol) also has to be registered as the window's "Restoration Class". 
When the window is initially created, register it using the `- (void)setRestorationClass:(Class <NSWindowRestoration>)restorationClass` method.

e.g. for a window controller, for initialization:

```
_myWindowController = [[MyWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MyWindowController"];
_myWindowController.window.restorationClass = self.class;
_myWindowController.window.identifier = @"MyWindow";
```

for restoration:

```
+ (void)restoreWindowWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier state:(NSCoder *)state completionHandler:(void (^)(NSWindow *, NSError *))completionHandler {

    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"MyWindow"]) {
        MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)NSApplication.sharedApplication.delegate;
        NSWindow *myWindow = appDelegate.myWindowController.window;

        completionHandler(myWindow, nil);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is one little code snipet:

```
+ (void)restoreWindowWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier state:(NSCoder *)state completionHandler:(void (^)(NSWindow *, NSError *))completionHandler
{
   // Get the window from the window controller,
   // which is stored as an outlet by the delegate.
   // Both the app delegate and window controller are
   // created when the main nib file is loaded.
   MyAppDelegate* appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate*)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   NSWindow* mainWindow = [appDelegate.windowController window];

   // Pass the window to the provided completion handler.
   completionHandler(mainWindow, nil);
}
```

Found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CoreAppDesign/CoreAppDesign.html).

Hopefully this will help you.

Edit:

Be sure you are implementing the protocol in your application class, remember you have to add it in your m file.

`@interface MyClass : FatherClass  <NSWindowRestoration>`

**I'm not 100% of the name of the protocol so that last line could be wrong, sorry I'm in a rush right now, it's either that or `NSWindowRestorationDelegate`.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to get that method called in the first place.

Comment: Aha, just figured it out.  My app is using `LSUIElement`.  As a result, it's not receiving notifications.  Seems to be a known bug.  Oh well.

Comment: Oh snap :S. You might want to add that detail to your answer and mark your question as answered. Good luck!

Comment: I'm not gonna call this "answered". Not sure how exactly this would be called if you don't have simply your Window in the mainNib. Currently I open my window with the usual "initWithWindowNibName" (which is already an instance so the window don't call a + method). Still missing a real Sample Code showing how this is supposed to work.